# How to check which array in support vector machine belongs to which label Python

Tags: python, svm, numpy-ndarray

I have a below code:

```
recognizer = SVC(C=1.0, kernel="linear", probability=True)
recognizer.fit(data["embeddings"], labels)
```

where labels is :

```
labels = {ndarray: (24,)}
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

and `data["embeddings"]` is a `list` of `ndarrays`. This list has a length of `24`

After running the `recognizer.fit(data["embeddings"], labels)`, if I print the length

```
print(len(recognizer.support_vectors_))
```

I got 13. This is my first question, when initially the length of `data["embeddings"]` and `labels` was 24, then how come it became `13`.

Now, I can access the each `ndarray` using `recognizer.support_vectors_[i]` where `i` can be from `0` to `12`, then in this case how would I know which label `ith` `ndarray` belongs to.?

I am new to `SVC` so can anyone please help me here. Thanks

Comment: The number of support vectors is determined by the number of slack variables allowed by the SVM. This is a function of `C`, which is the penalty of slack variables.

Comment: @erip Thanks but how can I relate which `ndarray` belongs to which label.?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - do you mean inference?

Comment: @erip Lets say, I do `recognizer.support_vectors_[3]`, then how would I know which label  `(0 or 1)`, it belongs to.?

Comment: I guess I don't see why you'd want to do that. The intuition is that the support vectors are arbitrarily close to the decision plane - they are basically an implementation detail that you shouldn't _have_ to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

**support_vectors_** attribute gives you with the number of support vectors recognized for the classification task once trained with the data and it has no relation to the number of samples (labels or feature rows).To understand what are support vectors, look here https://towardsdatascience.com/support-vector-machine-introduction-to-machine-learning-algorithms-934a444fca47

Comment: Thanks but how can I relate which `ndarray` belongs to which label.?

Answer (score 0):

Not all data points are support vectors. A support vector is a point that lies near the hyperplane. I'd suggest reading articles to better understand the algorithms, like here https://towardsdatascience.com/support-vector-machine-introduction-to-machine-learning-algorithms-934a444fca47

You could try support_ to get the indices, then from the indices get the label

Comment: Lets say I have indices as `3` then how can I get label, as `recognizer` do not have any label information stored.

Comment: you could do label[3], I've never tried this (and don't see why one would want to) but I believe it should preserve the indices from the original vectors. The index of the vector corresponds to the index of the label.